# Problems showing font symbols

Tags: jquery, html, css, reset

I have a problem with a Jquery Gallery.
In the template are user several font symbols for arrows (left/right), etc.
The gallery works ok, but I have problems with the symbols. they re not appearing. Could you please help me with this problem? Here below is the link: Many thanks!

http://psyhealth.ro/galerie.html

[image: Here is a printscreen with the problems marked in red]

Comment: It looks more like you either don't have Font Awesome installed/setup, or you are using an incorrect path to the font files in it (which can also cause those "block" dead characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by using an IFrame. It is an very urgent site. I have to go live in a few hours. After the event I will try you version Jester.
Thanks a lot!

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="800px" height="620px;" src="galerii.html">
 <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe>
```

I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE and it's working.

Comment: You have errors in your `width` and `height` attributes: they should contain only numbers. The `px` and `;` are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are trying to use font symbols from FontAwesome (http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/). If that's the case the current font-family you are using 'fontello' cannot render the ::before content code. My suggest is to use background-image instead

```
icon-th{
background-image:url('image/of/symbol.jpg');
}
```

This is more cross browser compatible.

**EDIT**: Alternatively you can download FontAwesome from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ and upload it to your website and change the font-family to FontAwesome